# Hash tables with long (100+ character) key names

Tags: c#, powershell, ordereddictionary

I am working on a data structure for a utility of mine, and I am TEMPTED to do a hash table in which the key is a very long string, specifically a file path. There are a number of reasons why this makes sense from a data standpoint, mainly the fact that the path is guaranteed unique. That said, every single example I have seen of a hash table has very short keys and potentially long values. So, I am wondering if that is just a function of easy examples? Or is there a performance or technical reason not to use long keys?
I will be using `$variable = New-Object Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary` for version agnostic ordering, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Long keys will be slower, yes (since calculating the hash code for a longer string takes longer). Will that be an issue for your context? Likely no - but you would need to profile to be 100% sure.

Comment: It may be worth noting that a [sorted dictionary will use more memory than a sorted list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/sorted-collection-types), with pretty nearly the same insert and retrieval time. You may want to factor this into your decision.

Answer (score 4):

**I think you are fine to have keys that have a long string.**

Under the hood, the key lookup in OrderedDictionary is doing this in

```
if (objectsTable.Contains(key)) {
```

objectsTable is of type Hashtable

If you follow the chain of getting the hash in the Hashtable class, you'll get to this:
    https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,4f6addb8551463cf

```
    // Internal method to get the hash code for an Object.  This will call
    // GetHashCode() on each object if you haven't provided an IHashCodeProvider
    // instance.  Otherwise, it calls hcp.GetHashCode(obj).
    protected virtual int GetHash(Object key)
    {
        if (_keycomparer != null)
            return _keycomparer.GetHashCode(key);
        return key.GetHashCode();
    }
```

So, the question becomes, what's the cost of getting a HashCode on a string?
    https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

The function GetHashCode, you'll see is a loop, but its only an O(n) function as it only grows based on the string length.  You'll notice the computation for a hash is a bit different on 32-bit machines than on others, but O(n) is a worse case for expansion of the algorithm.

There's other parts of the function, but I think this is the key part, as it's the part that can grow (src is the char* meaning a pointing to the characters in the string).

```
#if WIN32
                    // 32 bit machines.
                    int* pint = (int *)src;
                    int len = this.Length;
                    while (len > 2)
                    {
                        hash1 = ((hash1 << 5) + hash1 + (hash1 >> 27)) ^ pint[0];
                        hash2 = ((hash2 << 5) + hash2 + (hash2 >> 27)) ^ pint[1];
                        pint += 2;
                        len  -= 4;
                    }

                    if (len > 0)
                    {
                        hash1 = ((hash1 << 5) + hash1 + (hash1 >> 27)) ^ pint[0];
                    }
#else
                    int     c;
                    char *s = src;
                    while ((c = s[0]) != 0) {
                        hash1 = ((hash1 << 5) + hash1) ^ c;
                        c = s[1];
                        if (c == 0)
                            break;
                        hash2 = ((hash2 << 5) + hash2) ^ c;
                        s += 2;
                    }
#endif
```